# What parameter should I pass to ignore moving logins/users from source to destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, dacpac

I'm using dacpac file to compare schema between source and destination and generating a sql script to execute in the destination using Sqlpackage.exe.

If I do not want to move logins/users from source to destination what parameter should I use in sqlpackage command?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try

```
/p:ExcludeObjectType=Users
```

Comment: I'm getting error if I include the paramater. 'ExcludeObjectType' is not a valid argument for the 'Extract' action.

Comment: Use /p:ExcludeObjectType=User when publishing, not at extract. Also, get the latest version of SqlPackage here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46898

Answer (score 0):

There is a deployment contributor that was written to do just this (I wrote it whoop whoop):

http://agilesqlclub.codeplex.com/

Using this filter will ignore all security objects:

/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter=IgnoreSecurity"

Which should do what you want.

ed